# Brace-or-equal initializer causing C2098 and C2059 in Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015

The following, seemingly correct looking, code does not compile in Visual Studio 2015 RC, with errors like this:

```
test.cpp(6): error C2098: unexpected token after data member 'T'
  test.cpp(11): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Foo<int>' being compiled
test.cpp(6): error C2059: syntax error: '>'
```

The code:

```
template <typename, typename> struct X {};

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    X<int, T> * p = new X<int, T>;
};

int main()
{
   Foo<int> f;
}
```

Why is this and how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: @Barry I showed it on the code

Comment: @KerrekSB Interestingly, I may have found a [gcc bug](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30546631/2069064) as a result.

Comment: @Barry: Yeah, see my comment. Should test the recent GCC...

Comment: @KerrekSB [Here's 5.1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a732593d0a010f5c).

Comment: @Alexander1991: Can I replace your code with a minimal example? It would make it easier to read.

Comment: @KerrekSB of course you can and thank you for your precious time

Comment: @Alexander1991: Have a look now, and kindly double-check that the error still exists for you. (it does for GCC 4.9.2.) (But do feel free to roll back if this has destroyed the original meaning.)

Comment: @Barry: Interesting that people say it compiles on MSVS2013. I wonder if it's a regression in MSVC++?

Comment: A somewhat similar problem has been [reported here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1248282/c-code-compiles-with-v120-and-fails-with-v140). The answer from the development team is from May 28th, so hopefully the fix will make it into RTM.

Comment: @KerrekSB The error messages issued by VC++ 2015 RC for your updated code are `consoleapplication1.cpp(6): error C2098: unexpected token after data member 'T'` and `consoleapplication1.cpp(6): error C2059: syntax error: '>'`. I used `C2098` to find the issue referenced above on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Comment: @bogdan: Thanks! If you have access to MSVS and the original code (see my answer, I retained the original answer), please do feel free to update this question to be more accurate. (Though I'm generally satisfied that the answer is simply that it's a compiler problem, and a known one for that matter.)

Comment: @KerrekSB Done. And yeah, VC++ 2013 Update 4 does indeed compile the code. 2013 has limited support for *brace-or-equal-initializer*s for non-static data members - actually, more like *mostly-just-equal-initializer*s, as list initialization was found to be too buggy and was restricted in one of the updates. It looks like a regression slipped in when full support was implemented.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of a gcc bug?  Is it actually the same parsing problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler does not seem to implement C++ properly, specifically, the brace-or-equal initializer.

An easy work-around is to replace the brace-or-equals initializer with a constructor initializer:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    Foo() : p(new X<int, T>) {}
    //      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    X<int, T> * p;  // no initializer
};
```

---

<sub>Historical note: The fix in your original post, before I replaced it with a minimal example that reproduces the bug:</sub>

```
class ArdalanCollection : public ICollection<T>
{ 
public:
    ArdalanCollection()
    : storage(new Container_<int, T*>()), index(0) {}
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    virtual void add(T* obj) {
        storage->add(index++, obj);
    };

private:
    Container_<int, T*> *storage;   // no initializer here
    int index;
};
```

Comment: By the way, GCC 4.9.2 also fails to compile the original code, but Clang 3.7 succeeds.

Comment: it worked thanks, do you have any clue what the problem might be?

Comment: @Alexander1991: It's just a compiler bug, i.e. the compiler doesn't implement the language properly. These are relatively new language features, and adoption by vendors isn't instantaneous. If you want a C++ compliant compiler in Visual Studio, maybe give [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html#buildWindows) a try. It's pretty up-to-date.

Comment: I see, btw thanks for the great remedy and making my question clear and simple to read.

Comment: @Alexander1991: Narrowing the problem down is vital for effective communication :-)

Comment: Tried `X<int, T> * p = (X<int, T> *){new X<int, T>};`?  I find constructs like that can make vs2013 happier.