# non-static data member initialization with new expression

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```
#include <map>

template <typename T>
struct X {
    std::map<int, T>* storage = new std::map<int, T>();
};

int main() {
    X<int> x;
}
```

This compiles on [clang 3.6.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8d550fded9eb392), but fails to compile on [gcc 5.1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a732593d0a010f5c). It would compile, however, if the type of `storage` were instead `std::vector<T>*` (or just `T*`).

I'm fairly certain this is a compiler bug on gcc's part (edit: I submitted it as [66344](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66344)), but thought I'd ask to make sure: is there any reason the above example *shouldn't* compile?

gcc compile error:

```
main.cpp:5:51: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration    
     std::map<int, T>* storage = new std::map<int, T>();    
                                                   ^    

main.cpp:5:51: error: declaration of 'std::map<int, T> X<T>::T'    
main.cpp:3:11: error:  shadows template parm 'class T'    
 template <typename T>    
           ^

main.cpp:5:52: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token    
     std::map<int, T>* storage = new std::map<int, T>();    
                                                    ^    
main.cpp:5:46: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be at least 2)    
     std::map<int, T>* storage = new std::map<int, T>();    
                                              ^

In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/map:61:0,    
                 from main.cpp:1:    
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/bits/stl_map.h:96:11: note: provided for 'template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> class std::map'    
     class map    
           ^
```

Comment: Just to be sure: Are you using `gcc` or `g++`? I mixed that up one time too often...

Comment: @atlaste g++ 4.9.2 does not compile this too.

Comment: MSVC13 compiles it without errors. So seems to be an error

Comment: `g++` here also compiles it without errors. Also I'm quite sure it's properly formed code. e.g. `g++ -o main test.cpp`. Also works fine on `www.codingground.com` with g++ 4.9.2

Comment: @atlaste `g++ (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2` does not compile.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy You say `gcc`, not `g++`; they're different compilers - the one is for C, the other for C++. Be sure to use `g++`!

Comment: @atlaste I know that g++ is different from gcc. I've corrected - it is `g++ 4.9.2`. Don't know, why `g++ -v` and `g++ --version` gives different output.

Comment: @atlaste Dude, obviously we're using the C++ compiler - if we were using the C compiler, it would complain about all sorts of other things in this code.

Comment: **Workaround**: Use a *braced-init-list* to circumvent the (faulty) behavior of `g++` => `template <typename T> struct X { std::map<int, T>* storage { new std::map<int, T> () }; };`

Comment: @Barry okay, okay... I didn't mean to offend, was only trying to help. [On topic] I just noticed it also defaults to -std=c++03 on ubuntu, which gives a warning for my answer below. I think you're correct - it should compile.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp, G++ is not faulty, it's obeying the standard, see http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#325 (using a braced-init-list is a valid workaround though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another example of the problem described in [Core issue 325](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#325) (see the "Notes from the August, 2011 meeting" which have a very similar example), namely that the comma in the template argument list causes a parse failure when the compiler tries to determine where the end of the expression is.

The issue is still open, but the consensus of the committee is that it should be made to work (I don't know what will be changed to make it valid though).

Clang has implemented a workaround for some time (maybe tentatively parsing the expression and retrying if it fails) and Nathan Sidwell has just [un-suspended the relevant G++ bug and assigned it to himself](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2015-05/msg02285.html) so I hope he plans to fix it soon.

Comment: core issue 325 seems to be about default arguments

Comment: @sp2danny, keep reading, see the "Notes from the August, 2011 meeting" which have a very similar example

Answer (score 3):

Interesting, it should work IMO.

This one does compile:

```
#include <map>

template <typename T>
struct X {
   typedef std::map<int, T> mt;
   mt *storage = new mt();
};

int main() {
        X<int> x;
}
```

Apparently something goes wrong with the template argument expansion...

Compile with:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -std=c++11
```